# Legend and DataLabels with different "names"

Tags: highcharts

I haven't seen anyone else try to do this. I basically have a set of data to use for the pie chart in my "Series" collection, but in the legend rather then spit out these money values, I would like to "Categorize" them. I thought I had this working before by doing a "legend" update of the point names in the complete event, but now It seems to be changing the datalabel names as well. Here is my fiddle/code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyuo4f9g/1/

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$('#pie_chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                defer: false,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    colors: ['#77AEFF', '#94D664', '#E3DE51', '#D69567', '#D66664', '#aaaaab', '#a89375'],
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',            
        data: [
            ['$64,351.70', 90.0], {
                name: '$4,580.37',
                y: 6.0,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, ['$742.31', 1.0],
            ['$1231.43', 2.0],
            ['499.97', 1.0],
            ['$74.54', 0.0],
            ['$32.35', 0.0], 
        ]
    }]
}, function (chart) { // on complete
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart.legend.allItems[0].update({
            name: 'Current'
        });
        chart.legend.allItems[1].update({
            name: '31-60'
        });
        chart.legend.allItems[2].update({
            name: '61-90'
        });
        chart.legend.allItems[3].update({
            name: '91-120'
        });
        chart.legend.allItems[4].update({
            name: '121-150'
        });
        chart.legend.allItems[5].update({
            name: '151-180'
        });
        chart.legend.allItems[6].update({
            name: 'Over 180'
        });
    });
});
```

});

I basically want the datalabels to show the monetary values (i.e. $##.##) and percentage. But the legend to continue to show "Current, 31-60, etc"

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, So I learned that the legend attribute has a "labelFormatter" option which lets you create a sort of LookUp table of values to label names for the legend. Pretty cool.

http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6202

So basically my legend attribute looks like this now:

```
        legend: {
        enabled: true,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return {
                '$64,351.70' : 'Current',
                '$4,580.37': '31-60',
                '$742.31': '61-90',
                '$1231.43': '91-120',
                '$499.97': '121-150',
                '$74.54': '151-180',
                '$32.35': 'Over 180'
            }[this.name];
        }
    },enter code here
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyuo4f9g/2/